# Chat app send and delivered status

Tags: android, chat, send, status

I am creating a chat application. My issue is that I have a list of messages to a user. When I sent a message, it is shown as a chat bubble and I need to show as status as in 'whatsapp' application. When a message is sent I need to show a tick mark in the same message bubble and when delivered two tick marks need to be shown as in whatsapp application. The server is sending the sent and delivered responses. Can anybody tell me a way to solve this?

Thanks in advance
Sundeep.S.

Comment: You are already getting the response from the server? What's the question then?

Comment: When I sent a message I already created a bubble in the chat list with the text message. As I am getting response from the server I need to update the status in the same bubble. I am asking how to add this status tick mark in the same bubble in the chat list?

Comment: This highly depends on your specific implementation. I'd suggest adding an ImageView to your ListView rows and filling that with the appropriate image.

Comment: Yes that is  my problem. I have image view in my listview layout. Actually what happens is that, as I have created a bubble in the chat list for the message which I sent and when the response comes from sever, it creates another bubble below the message bubble and the imageview gets updated there.

Comment: Now how could we smell that problem from the description in your question? An answer can only be as specific as the question. Your question is not very specific unfortunately, and you might want to get a specific answer, so please consider adding more details to your question.